# Update specific value in JSON with nested object in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a JSON field in my database that need to update and I use `json_set`. But I only want to update one key value..

this is the json:

```
{
   "a":[
      {
         "fin":"14",
         "diff":"",
         "sched":"14",
         "pilot":"none",
         "vehicle":"none"
      }
   ],
   "b":[
      {
         "fin":"",
         "diff":"",
         "sched":"15",
         "pilot":"none",
         "vehicle":"none"
      }
   ]
}
```

I've try to update using this pdo query in php

```
$currentDate = date('m/d/y');               
    try{        
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=mylocal;dbname=mydb','','');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE , PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $update = $pdo->prepare(
            "UPDATE Chart
                SET
                    ship_data = JSON_SET(ship_data, '$.b', JSON_OBJECT('fin','35'))
                WHERE
                date_recorded = '$currentDate' "
                            );
        $update->execute();
    }catch(PDOExeption $e){
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
        $pdo=null;
```

this is the result :

```
{
   "a":[
      {
         "fin":"14",
         "diff":"",
         "sched":"14",
         "pilot":"",
         "vehicle":""
      }
   ],
   "b":[
      {
         "fin":"35"
      }
   ]
}
```

how can I update only the key `fin` and retain the other objects?

Comment: Do not update `$.b`, but `$.b.fin`? (And not with an object then, but a plain string value.)

Comment: @CBroe I've already try that `JSON_SET(ship_data, '$.b.fin','35')` and it doesn't update anything...

Comment: btw my mysql version is 5.7.13

Comment: Right, `b` is an array, so you should use the path `$.b[0].fin`